# How to call from SIM 2 in Android?

Tags: android, call

I am building an android application where I want to call from SIM2 to particular number from my devices.

Below is the main code which I found from other links but that not useful for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 1); //For sim 2
        intent.putExtra("simSlot", 1); //For sim 2
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "**********"));
```

I am having OnePluse2 device. I checked other application like trueBalance and **mubble** that working fine. They are calling from SIM2 for checking it Balance.

But How I can also call from SIM2 and check there Balance!

can any one help me to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for samsung phones.Basically android does not provide an option to choose the sim to make a call, it is actually provided by the device manufacturers.There is not any official documentation available to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I found that the above mention apps were able to achieve that. Any idea about the same?

Comment: they are directly calling from sim 2

Comment: As far as i know it is not possible, instead you can open dial pad with the numbers typed programmatically and prompt the user to make the call...

Comment: From what I've seen of the many similar questions, there's no **one** standard way (although there may be some ways that are common to a lot of phones). I assume that existing apps that correctly do this must have a collection (possibly hard-won through trial and error) of _if I'm on this hardware, do this_ type tests.

Comment: How I can do that? Is there any link you can suggested to me which can help me?